# Downloading a playlist youtube-dl

Tags: youtube-dl

I have been trying to use this command on mac:

```
youtube-dl "link" ffmpeg -i Lec*.mp4 -map_channel 0.1.1 -ac 1 -vcodec copy fixed.mp4
```

to download a playlist which has some audio cut off but I keep on getting this error:

```
Usage: youtube-dl [OPTIONS] URL [URL...]
youtube-dl: error: no such option: -m
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Are you trying to pipe something into `ffmpeg` without the `|` or `>`?

Comment: @Mioriin I actually was just copy and pasting a code I found on a youtube video so it was exactly that, which am I suppose to use to fix my problem ?

Comment: Blindly running unknown commands from unknown and unverified sources on the internet is a `BAD IDEA!!`

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's probably [this comment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZK3O402wf1c&lc=UgjdqPfRPXS6h3gCoAEC) that you copied the commands from, right?

The solution is that these are two commands, they are supposed to be executed separately: First download the video file, then process it.

```
$ youtube-dl "link"
$ ffmpeg -i Lec*.mp4 -map_channel 0.1.1 -ac 1 -vcodec copy fixed.mp4
```

Side note: It would have been much easier if you had given the source of the commands from the start...